# Tab panels with maxcdn css dont work

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is basic JQuery to show and hide panels when a list item in the menu is clicked but I can't get my code to work.The CSS I am using is max cdn so I am not sure if I need to have my own CSS file for this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
        <script src ="PhpProject1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tabs a').click(function(){
                var $this =$(this);
                $('.panel').hide();
                $('.tabs a.active').removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active').blur();});
            }); // end ready
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabContainer">
            <h2>Tab Heading</h2>
            <div class=col-xs-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li  class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
              </ul>
                <div id ="panel1" class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">   
                     #panel1
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">content
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div id ="panel2" class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">   
                     #panel2
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">content
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div id ="panel3" class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">   
                     #panel3
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">content
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using script on a css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is that you have a script tag pointing to CSS.

This:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
```

should be this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/sandstone/bootstrap.css">
```

Even after fixing that, there are other issues too. E.g. `$('.tabs a').click(...` doesn't do anything, because there is no element on the page with the class "tabs". Changing this to `$('.nav-tabs a').click(...` is a good start, though I still think you have more work to do.

**EDIT**

Here's one way to fix things up. New script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-tabs li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('#' + $this.find('a').attr('href')).show();
        $('.nav-tabs .active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active').blur();
        return false;
    });
}); // end ready
```

New tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="panel1">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="panel2">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="panel3">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

New panels:

```
<div id="home" class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        #home
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Home content
    </div>
</div>
<div id ="panel1" class="panel panel-primary" style="display: none">
    <div class="panel-heading">   
        #panel1
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">content
    </div>    
</div>
<div id ="panel2" class="panel panel-primary" style="display: none">
    <div class="panel-heading">   
        #panel2
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">content
    </div>    
</div>
<div id ="panel3" class="panel panel-primary" style="display: none">
    <div class="panel-heading">   
        #panel3
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">content
    </div>    
</div>
```

A couple things to note:

1. I set up the click handler on the `li`s instead of the `a`s, since this is where the "active" class lives.
2. I used the `href` attribute on the anchor tags to decide which panel to display.
3. I made a new "home" panel and set all the others to the initial style `display:none`.

Comment: I tried your fixes and I see the home panel is linked to the home li for the first time but when I click on the other tabs the other panels do'nt show up and when I return to click on the home menu also it doesnt show the original panel

Comment: @user1721546 Ah, sorry, had forgotten to include the snippet that has the proper `href`s.

Comment: @user1721546 See my updated code above (specifically the "new tabs" snippet).

Comment: One more question on styling I am trying to get the same look and feel as the tabs in http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp but somehow the font looks different now . Do you know what could have changed it ?

Comment: @user1721546 Not without knowing what you changed! :-) Maybe ask a new question about fonts with your current code.

Comment: I did not change anything in your code the problem is I had not see how the style sheet looks like before because I had it in a script tag. Now I see the style sheet used in W3 schools is different .Once I swapped the style sheet I got the same look .thanks again for your quick responses